# read uncommited input in Knockout.js enter handler

Tags: knockout.js

I have a form which uses knockout.js where uses can input values and then click a button or press enter to apply the values to the current VM.

Everything works fine when I click the button or tab off of the input field before I press enter, but if I press enter without tabbing off of the input field, I am reading the stale value (or no value if field has not yet lost focus).

```
        self.triggerApplyInputByEnter = function (data, event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                self.ApplyInput();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Markup:

```
                 <table>
                   <tbody data-bind="foreach: Inputs">
                     <tr>
                         <td><input type="text" placeholder="Start" data-bind="value: InputStart, event: { keypress: $parent.triggerApplyInputByEnter }" /></td>
                         <td><input type="text" placeholder="End"  data-bind="value: InputEnd, event: { keypress: $parent.triggerApplyInputByEnter }" /></td>
                     </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            <td>
               <a href="#" title="" data-bind="click: ApplyInput" ><span>Apply Input</span></a>
            </td>
```

My intuition is that my observables that are bound to my input fields are not being updated until the input field loses focus.  Any guidance on how to read the uncommitted value in the keypress handler or force a input fields to databind when I press Enter or any other way to read the latest values when I press Enter?

Update: I found that using "valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" works in that it updates the observable with every keypress, which would seem inefficient if lots of data is input, but for my case is good enough.

```
<td><input type="text" placeholder="Start" data-bind="value: InputStart, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown', event: { keypress: $parent.triggerApplyInputByEnter }" /></td>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this would solve your problem, but did you look at the [hasFocus](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html) binding? I've never encountered your problem, but we could possibly begin there, unless you want to make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [textInput](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html) binding was designed for real-time cross-browser updates. This will serve your use case.

The `valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"` binding can fail in a number of scenarios, like mobile.